# C++ - Determine if const char* points to string literal or dynamic object

Tags: c++, string, dynamic

```
void delete_str(const char* theString) {
    // if (theString is pointing to dynamic objects delete it)
        delete[] theString;
    // else do nothing
}

int main() {
    char str[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};

    const char* str0 = "abc"; // assign "abc" to str0
    char* str1 = new char[strlen("abc")+1]; for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) str1[i] = str[i]; // assign "abc" to str1

    delete_str(str0); // run time error
    delete_str(str1); // ok
}
```

In this example, I'd like to define a function `delete_str()`to delete what `theString` is pointing to. But how could I determine if it points to a string literal or not?

Comment: You generally can't. Use `std::string` and you won't have to worry about any of this.

Comment: `delete_str(const char* theString)`  only "sees" the `theString` pointer, there is absolutely no way to determine what kind of memory `theString` points to.

Comment: Isn't `strlen("abc")` defined to _always_ be 3? Also, that loop could be simplified to `std::memcpy(str1, str, 4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot determine that. The programmer needs to manually keep track of how objects that a pointer points to were created.

That is one of the reasons raw pointers created from `new` should not be used directly, except in the implementation of a class specifically managing a single such allocation.

Use `std::string`. You can obtain a null-terminated C string from a `std::string` using its `.c_str()` or `.data()` member functions.

Only use raw pointers as non-owning pointers. Then you will never have to decide whether you need to `delete` it or not. There are smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr` and containers such as `std::vector` in addition to the `std::string` class, all of which will handle ownership and correct `delete` of non-array and array objects for you automatically.